# bash: pip: команда не найдена

Tags: python, linux, debian, pip

хочу установить python модуль на debian 10 32bit он мне выдаёт такую ошибку   `bash: pip: команда не найдена` как исправить?

Comment: `sudo apt install python-pip`

Comment: pip3 не срабатывает?

Comment: @Дмитрий, pip3 неработает

Comment: @RomanKonoval E: Невозможно найти пакет python-pip

Comment: @tasiba3135 да, понял уже( Версия `python` 3? Может это `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: @Дмитрий E: Невозможно найти пакет python3-pip

Comment: @tasiba3135 тогда надо больше информации)

Comment: @Дмитрий Python 3.7.3

Comment: Сначала сделайте `sudo apt update`, а потом уже `sudo apt install python-pip`

Comment: @RomanKonoval, «а потом» не install, а `$ apt-cache search python pip`

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в /etc/apt/sources.list - там должна быть строчка

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main
```

если нет - добавьте. Потом

```
apt update
apt install python3-pip # или python-pip для второго Python
```